# How much connection is there between Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, soft-question

How much connection is there between Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Topology?

I am looking for general highlights, not complex details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"How much connection is there between the wheel and bike racing ?"

Basically, one is an essential tool for the other : algebraic topology is full of commutative algebra concepts, such as polynomial rings or exact sequences, and uses many commutative algebra methods or results, such as the five-lemma or diagram-chasing arguments.

Comment: Do modules appear in algebraic topology?

Comment: Yes, all the time. For a cheap example, abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules!

Comment: And for a slightly less cheap example, the cohomology of the total space of a fiber bundle is a module over the cohomology of the base space.

Comment: And for an important and more algebra-heavy example, the mod-p cohomology of any space is a module over the (rather complicated, and in particular non-commutative!) Steenrod algebra.

Comment: Oops, you were asking about *commutative* algebra.  I suppose I should amend my statement: the mod-p homology of any space is a comodule over the (commutative) dual Steenrod algebra.  (The Steenrod algebra is actually a Hopf algebra, and it has non-commutative multiplication and commutative comultiplication, so its dual has commutative multiplication and non-commutative comultiplication.)